# Find content-type of sharepoint file

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I need to find out the mime-type from the object of type `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File`. For example - if it's a pdf, I need a field which would contain "application/pdf".

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are looking for a [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types), in SharePoint CSOM API the closest property you could get is [file type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.file_x0020_type?view=sharepoint-server):

```
var file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl);
ctx.Load(file, f => f.ListItemAllFields);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var fileType = file.ListItemAllFields["File_x0020_Type"];
```

To get MIME type, [`System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping.aspx) could be utilized from .NET (4.5 or above):

```
var file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl);
ctx.Load(file);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(file.Name);
```

Comment: Yes, thanks Vadim. I am looking for mime type. But if I am not wrong, this snippet would give me the file extension, while I want the mime type, similar to what we get in HttpResponse

Comment: @Naman, that's right, first snippet returns file extension but second one  returns MIME type (`mimetype` var)

Comment: But that's not what I am trying to do.  What I am actually trying to do is to get the actual file type rather than the extension. For example - if I am processing an email attachment, I am figuring out the mime-type from Attachment.ContentType rather than Attachment.Name. Then from ContentType(e.g. "application/pdf"), I am mapping the extension. That's what I am trying to do with a SharePoint file